# Homogeneous or preserve multiplication?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

Define a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

If $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}: f(ax) = af(x)$:

I've seen $f(x)$ to be dubbed 'homogeneous' or 'preserves scaler multiplication'.

Are these two terms equivalent?

Also, what if a function 'preserves addition', like $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ ? Does it also have a nickname?

Comment: If $f(ax)=af(x)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ is a linear map... so it's continuous, linear, homogeneous... (But notice that for higher dimension spaces, it won't be true anymore...)

Comment: A function $f$ for which holds $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is called an additive Map : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map. However it is not a nickname.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean 1-space. I've made an edit.